# Making a style file that defines a style for a definition

Tags: amsthm, newtheorem

How can I include the following style for a definition in a style file?  I am using the packages `xcolor` (with the option `x11names`), `amsmath`, `amsthm`, and `amssymb`.

```latex
    \newtheoremstyle{typex-definition} % name of style
    {8pt}       % measure of space above definition, e.g. {3pt}
    {8pt}       % measure of space below definition, e.g. {3pt}
    {\itshape}  % name of font for body of example
    {}          % measure of space to indent, e.g. {3pt}
    {\bfseries\itshape}           % name of font for heading
    {\textcolor{DarkOrange3}{.}}  % punctuation between heading and body
    { }         % space after theorem heading
    {\thmname{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
     \textcolor{DarkOrange3}{\textbf{\thmnumber{#2}}}
     \thmnote{\textit{({#3})}} }
    
    \theoremstyle{typex-definition}
    \newtheorem{definition}{\textcolor{Blue3}{Definition}}[section]
```

Comment: what do you mean by the question?? You can put those lines in `wibble.sty`  then you have made a package (style file) usable as `\usepackage{wibble}`

Comment: Thought it was more complicated and needed some specific configuration and syntax.

Comment: No, as shown in the answer posted you could add more but just doing what I said is enough to answer the quesion.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is interesting, when are the first 2 lines required from my answer please, for CTAN package style files and similar? I (it appears incorrectly) assumed they were always required for `.sty` files

Comment: They are never required. The first line is just a command we added so that you could add something so that you got an early, easily understood error if you used the `.sty` file with the pre-1994 latex2.09 system. I does nothing at all if used with latex2e. The second line puts a useful message in the log file with the package name and version, useful for debugging. @LaccaseTVersicolor

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the explanation, I modified my answer although I am tempted to wiki or delete my answer as you solved it in the comments first. I answered because of the first 2 lines of the code and my mistaken belief they were required. Should I wiki or delete it or are you okay with it?

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor your answer is fine I don't really need more points:-)

Comment: This looks suspiciously like `amsthm` syntax, so I've added the tag.

Comment: Yes it requires `amsthm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference whether you place the `\newtheoremstyle` declaration in a `.sty` file or not, so I'll make an example with the declaration in the document preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

% this can go in a .sty file, but it's not necessary

\newtheoremstyle{typex-definition} % name of style
  {8pt}       % measure of space above definition, e.g. {3pt}
  {8pt}       % measure of space below definition, e.g. {3pt}
  {\itshape}  % name of font for body of example
  {}          % measure of space to indent, e.g. {3pt}
  {\bfseries\itshape}           % name of font for heading
  {\textcolor{DarkOrange3}{.}}  % punctuation between heading and body
  { }         % space after theorem heading
  {%
   \thmname{#1}% heading
   \thmnumber{ \textcolor{DarkOrange3}{#2}}% number
   \thmnote{ {\normalfont\itshape(#3)}}%
 }

\theoremstyle{typex-definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{\textcolor{Blue3}{Definition}}[section]
\newtheorem*{altdefinition}{\textcolor{Blue3}{Definition}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
This is the text of the definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[Some name]
This is the text of the definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{altdefinition}
This is the text of the definition.
\end{altdefinition}

\begin{altdefinition}[Some name]
This is the text of the definition.
\end{altdefinition}

\end{document}
```

I fixed a few particulars: the space separating the number from the heading and the space in front of the note should go in the arguments to `\thmnumber` and `\thmnote`, otherwise those spaces would be unconditionally added if there is no number or no note, see the unnumbered `altdefinition` to see it.

You need no `\textbf` and `\textit`, because they're already set by `\bfseries\itshape`.

[image]

Comment: Can I ask why you used `\normalfont` with the note?  I want the note to display as italic bold.

Comment: @Ephram Then remove `\normafont\itshape`

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this perhaps, per [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) in the comments above the `\ProvidesPackage` command "puts a useful message in the log file with the package name and version, useful for debugging" although it is not required:

```
\ProvidesPackage{CustTheorem}[2022/04/25 Custom Theorem Style]

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheoremstyle{typex-definition} % name of style
{8pt}       % measure of space above definition, e.g. {3pt}
{8pt}       % measure of space below definition, e.g. {3pt}
{\itshape}  % name of font for body of example
{}          % measure of space to indent, e.g. {3pt}
{\bfseries\itshape}           % name of font for heading
{\textcolor{DarkOrange3}{.}}  % punctuation between heading and body
{ }         % space after theorem heading
{\thmname{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\textcolor{DarkOrange3}{\textbf{\thmnumber{#2}}}
\thmnote{\textit{({#3})}} }
  
\theoremstyle{typex-definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{\textcolor{Blue3}{Definition}}[section]
```

Other people will probably have better answers so wait a while to see if people suggest something superior. Load the package using `\usepackage{CustTheorem)` and save the file as `CustTheorem.sty` or whatever you want to change the name to be (making sure to change the `\ProvidesPackage{}` name to the same name). There are answers on here about where to place custom `.sty` files so that Latex can find them without having to place the file in the same folder as your document, comment if you cannot find them and I'll find you a recent one to help.

Comment: Felicitations @LaccaseTVersicolor

Comment: No worries, make sure you tick either of our answers or any answer (it doesn't matter who is it is as long as it answered your question) so that the `community bot` doesn't keep repeating this question to the top of the feed every few months. Hope either of our answers helped!